# Expression Engine, filter relationship's entry by category id

Tags: expressionengine

I have the channel Market and Family. Both have the same expressionengine's category group.
I want to print out all the entries of the channel Market with the category XY, and for each market I want to print ONLY the first family entry of category XY related to it.

In my solution, seems that the category parameter inside the relationship field "market-families" doesn't work. here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="Market" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
        {if "{url_title}" == "{segment_3}"}
            <li class="active">
        {if:else}
            <li>
        {/if}

        {market-families orderby="title" sort="asc" category="{segment_2_category_id}" limit="1"}
            <a href="{base_url}{segment_2}/{url_title}/{market-families:url_title}">{title}</a> 
        {/market-families}
        </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Legend:

{segment_2_category_id} -> plugin to get the category id from a segment.

market-families -> Multiple relationship field inside channel Market

**Thank you for any help :)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually entering the category id in the parameter instead of using the plugin just to verify that it's not the plugin?

I couldn't find any specific reference to the relationship field being able to use the category parameter in ExpressionEngine's documentation: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html

Comment: I tried but nothing. Anway I found a solution: Rewrite the code with exp:query ...